# How to call servlet through ajax to load a value,what the servlet returns to the html tabel rowcell

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am new to AJAX,so help me out please.

My Ajax Coding:

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
                alert("Hello trial");
                $('#weight').click(function(event) {  
                    alert("Hello click");
                 $.get('UpdateWeight',function(responseText) { 
                        alert("After the getJson");
                        $('#materialweigh').text(responseText);         
                        alert("Hello responsetext");
                    });
                });
            });
```

My Jsp page:

```
<body>
        <div>
            <table id="mytable" width="350px" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>S.No</td>
                    <td>Bag Weight</td>
                    <td id="materialweigh">Material Weight</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="call_2();">OK</button>
            <input type="button" value="GetWeight" id="weight"/>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Servlet Coding:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    System.out.println("Inside Get Method");
    try {
        servletweight = request.getParameter("weight");
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\d+\\.\\d{2}$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(servletweight.trim());
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            request.setAttribute("Weight", servletweight.trim());
            System.out.println("Weight Captured::" + servletweight.trim());
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().write(servletweight);
        }
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
```

> Call_2 function:

```
function call_2(){

            var rows = document.getElementById("mytable").getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
            var total=rows+1
            $("#mytable").last().append("<tr><td>"+total+"</td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
        }
```

I want to get the weight from the servlet to fill it up in the html table,it's a continuous process,so ajax is needed to do process without loading the whole page.

Comment: where is the `call_2();` function?

Comment: @Sionnach733 I have posted that function too,it's just to append the rows dynamically

Comment: does the get method in the servlet get called? ie console should print "Inside Get Method"

Comment: No I m not getting it, When GetWeight button is clicked,it gives only one alert i.e alert('HelloClick'), means it's not reaching the servlet.

Comment: Do UpdateWeight url pattern invokes the getMethod in the servlet?or should i wanna mention the type of the method anywhere to invoke get Method??

Comment: I put the code into jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QvD3e/ and all alerts are shown. it looks like the servlet isnt connected properly. is it in your web.xml file?

Comment: Using Annotation I have configured it, like :@WebServlet(name = "CommunicationEg", urlPatterns = {"/CommPortSample", "/UpdateWeight"})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your web.xml you should specify the servlet:

```
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>ServletName</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ServletName</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.package.ServletName</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletName</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/UpdateWeight</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

the ajax request will then access the servlet when the button is clicked.

Comment: it is invoking the method properly,after adding the details in XML